# What is rotational inertia or moment of inertia? What is its equivalent in linear quantities?

Tags: physics

What is rotational inertia or moment of inertia? What is its equivalent in linear quantities?
I know what rotational inertia is; I just can't think of the equivalent in linear quantities please help.

Comment: Could you clarify your question. Your first sentence _asks_ what rotational inertia is, yet your 3rd sentence says you _know_ what rotational inertia is.

Comment: I know what it is but I can't figure out what the same thing is for linear quantities. If that makes sense. I only know the first part of the question.

Comment: You might want to consider linear momentum vs. angular momentum.  As presently framed it isn't really a Question that can be answered by reasoned mathematical arguments, so I'm voting to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

The linear equivalent is the mass $m$

e.g. compare kinetic energy for rotation and translation
$$
\frac{1}{2} I \omega^2
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{2} m v^2
$$